# Set up a Mac to run OSX (None Browser) application in pure kiosk mode

Tags: bash, plist

I've been trying for a number of months, using many methods, to run a Nuiteq Application called Snowflake on our 10 Mac Minis attached to touch-screens in pure Kiosk mode. I'm using Yosemite. These machines must be able to:

1. Run full windowless screens
2. Have the Dock and Menu Bar disabled
3. Access to finder removed
4. Not show the default cursor, and only use multitouch functionality in Snowflake

Unfortunately, I don't have build access to the application, and can't add things like `NSApplicationPresentationHideMenuBar`to Snowflake as it is proprietary software.

Initially I began by adding `LUSIPresentationMode` to the info.plist file of the app, with some success. The dock and menu bar was still appearing. Then I created a plist in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` that replaced finder with the app. It looked like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>POSIXSpawnType</key>
    <string>App</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <dict>
        <key>SuccessfulExit</key>
        <true/>
        <key>AfterInitialDemand</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.apple.FindertoSnowflake</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Applications/snowflake/run.sh</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.finder</string>
    <key>ThrottleInterval</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and I wrote 2 short scripts that loaded and unloaded the plist to stop/start the app. (The following is to start it)

```
PASSWORD=password

echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S killall Finder
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.Finder.plist
launchctl load -w /Users/snowbloke/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.FindertoSnowflake.plist
```

And this to stop:

```
PASSWORD=password

echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S killall -vu snowflake
```

And then, the software wouldn't hide the main cursor so I had to write in a keyboard emulation of Fn+F3 to the start the script. Otherwise there would have been 2 sets of interaction going on between the touch drivers used by Snowflake and the OS. This was very annoying.

```
osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to key code 99"

exit 0
```

Each mac logs straight into the app from start up.

After doing all of this and running tests over time, the users are **still** able to get into the OS desktop and finder just starts running. For some reason either the menu bar or dock turn up on screen. **Is there a more robust solution? What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Can anyone give me an answer? Does El Capitan provide a better solution?